# Pause method in pygame doesn't stop sound from playing

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I am trying to make a sound player with python and this works fine. But when I try to use the pause() function on the mixer it wont recognize, that it should pause. Also when I try to run the pause method from an other class it doesnt work either. I would be pretty thankful, if someone could help me.

```
import pygame
from pygame import *

sound_bassdrum = 'bassdrum.wav'

class soundsMixer:
    def __init__(self):
        mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096)
        mixer.init()

    def pauseMixer(self):
        mixer.pause()

    def playBassdrum(self):
        self.bassdrum = pygame.mixer.Sound(sound_bassdrum)
        self.bassdrum.play()

appMixer = soundsMixer()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
  You're most of the way there, but we need you to fill in the *entire* example.

Comment: Is it showing any error ?

Comment: No, there is no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the you are not able to pause it properly because you are running the `.pause` method on the mixer(Although all channels must be paused according to documentation). But you are actually not pausing the Sound object that was created at
 `self.bassdrum = pygame.mixer.Sound(sound_bassdrum)`

Try doing something like this and let me know if it worked.
Add this function to your class

```
def pause_soundobject(self, soundobj):
    soundobj.stop()
```

Now use this method and pass in the `self.bassdrum` as soundobj.

Comment: I tryed it and I got this error now: AttributeError: 'Sound' object has no attribute 'pause'

Comment: It's `soundobj.stop()` not `.pause`